# Sending JSON object on HTTP post request in Android

Tags: android, json

I can successfully send params on post in Android but now i face the problem of sending a JSON object that has 2 key-value fields. I keep on inserting these fiels as a string and that's not correct. 
This is what i need to make work:

```
"name" : "test_name",
    "settings" : {
        "id" : "123",
        "email" : "test@test.com"
    }
```

I can test send the "name" as a namepairvalue.

```
List<BasicNameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>();
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));

JSONObject settings = new JSONObject();
settings.put("id", id);
settings.put("email", email);

nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("settings", settings.toString()));
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
```

in database i have something like this: `Settings ===> {"id": 123, "email": "test@test.com"}`, so not even remotely the correct form from above.

is there something i am missing? I get that i am doing this wrong but would like a fresh idea on this.
Thank you.

Comment: How is it not what you're sending?  It's exactly what you are sending, indeed.

Comment: this is what i am sending for testing.yes.

Comment: Could you show us the part of server side code which parses the incoming json? Because android side seems ok

Comment: unfortunatelly i have no access to the server side..i have no clue how it's parsed/ but i saw some preexisting data, imported and it's looks right, so i am guessing my problem is in the android still..

Comment: You are right, it was on the server side. Thx.